# Validate form and submit without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form that I need to validate, and I also need it to submit without refreshing the page. I was able to get a form to validate and submit, but the page refreshed. And then I was able to get a form to submit without, but I couldn't get validation to work.

I've looked at a ton of tutorials and posts on here, and I feel like this is the right overall format...I'm just sure I'm missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#addstudent").validate({
                debug: false,
                rules: {
                    studentid: "required",
                    teacher: "required",
                    assignment: "required",
                    date: "required",
                },
                messages: {
                    studentid: "Please enter the student's ID number.",
                    teacher: "Please enter your name.",
                    assignment: "Please select a tutoring assignment.",
                    date: "Please select a day.",
                },                 
                submitHandler: function(form) {

          $.ajax({
              url: 'add.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: $("form.addstudent").serialize(),         
              success: function() {
            $("#studentid").val(""), $('#studentid').focus(), $('#results').load('addresults.php', function(){
                });

              }
          });

          return false;
       }
    });
    });
```

And here is the code for my form:

```
<form name="addstudent" id="addstudent" action="" method="post">

    <fieldset><legend>Add student to tutoring list</legend>
    <div><label for="studentid">ID number</label><input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid"></div>

    <div><label for="day">Date</label><select name="date" id="date">
    <option value="">Please select a day</option>
    <option value="mon">Monday <? echo $monday; ?></option>
    <option value="tue">Tuesday <? echo $tuesday; ?></option>
    <option value="wed">Wednesday <? echo $wednesday; ?></option>
    <option value="thu">Thursday <? echo $thursday; ?></option>
    <option value="fri">Friday <? echo $friday; ?></option>
    </select></div>

    <div><label for="assignment">Tutoring assignment</label><select name="assignment" id="assignment">
    <option value="">Please select an assignment</option>
    <option value="att">Activity Time</option>
    <option value="acc">ACC</option>
    <option value="tech">ACC Tech </option>
    <option value="ast">After School</option>
    </select></div>

    <div><label for="teacher">Assigning teacher</label><input type="text" name="teacher" id="teacher"></div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**EDIT**: First edit (now deleted) dramatically changed the question. Apologies for any frustration that caused. Answer selected below solved the problem with this form in and of itself.

Comment: Intercept the form submit event: [jQuery Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Turn form from Post to an onclick. Make the onclick call the jquery

Comment: i hope you are validating server side as well

Comment: This can't be correct:  `$("form.addstudent").serialize()` because `addstudent` is an `id`, not a `class`.  Try:  `$("form#addstudent").serialize()`, or just `("#addstudent").serialize()`.

Comment: OP, do you still see the page refresh if you comment out the call to `.load`?

Comment: OP, have you totally changed your entire question now, rendering all previous answers useless?

Comment: Sorry. That's my fault due to ignorance. I just assumed it was the form and hadn't thought to test the form by itself until all of the comments indicated that the form worked with those minor tweaks. My apologies. Should I start another question? I'm new to posting on stackoverflow, and don't want to fubar the etiquette any more than I already have.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to discourage that but in this case, the whole thing went upside down.... it's probably best to start again... as concisely as possible.  Although, I'll let somebody else tell you that you aren't getting the `document.ready` because you are using `.load` to load the page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up `class` with `id`.  Your form is:

```
<form name="addstudent" id="addstudent" action="" method="post">
```

But you targeted it by `class`:

```
data: $("form.addstudent").serialize(),
```

when it should be targeted by `id`:

```
data: $("form#addstudent").serialize(),
```

or more concisely:

```
data: $("#addstudent").serialize(),
```

[Working Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/5UqRm/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/5UqRm/2/

Notice that nothing is refreshing.

Comment: Would this be causing the problem? I'm not familiar with the validation plugin, but if `submitHandler` runs after the data is validated, I would expect that the ajax submission would work fine even with `$("form.addstudent")` except that the POST data would be empty.

Comment: @Emily, because sometimes `.validate()` won't work at all if you have improper selectors.  Working on a fiddle.

Comment: But in the fiddle you just posted, it seems to still work (not refresh) when I change it to `data: $("form.addstudent").serialize()`. Do you see that behavior as well? I'm looking at the validate plugin source but I don't yet see how it could possibly know that `$("form.addstudent")` is a problem because there are no exceptions thrown: it seems like it should be the same from the plugin's perspective as if the function had `data: []` in there.

Comment: @Emily, yes, in this case, the improper selector is not causing the refresh... also acknowledged in my edits.  Although, an improper selector will cause nothing to be submitted.

Comment: Yep, it should be the same as submitting with `data: []`. This refresh is still very mysterious though, as I don't see any reason why `.load` can't be called inside the success callback for a POST request. See http://jsfiddle.net/etDhd/

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but I don't think the commas are a problem (though it's definitely bad style). :) Seems to be valid syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/KzBdp/ (no exceptions)

Comment: @Emily, sigh... yes, it's all the OP's fault... see the edited question.

Comment: Ah. Funny, I was just reading this the other day... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 0):

Setup your form rules and validation as you have before, but do not include the submitHandler.  I am not saying there is anything wrong with it, but here is how I know how to do what you are looking to do:

```
$("form.addstudent").submit(HandleSubmit);
    function HandleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'add.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("form.addstudent").serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $("#studentid").val(""), $('#studentid').focus(), $('#results').load('addresults.php', function () {
            });

        }
    });
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/56DQv/)

Comment: This is not going to solve anything, because there is absolutely nothing wrong with the built-in `submitHandler:`

Comment: It will solve stopping the default behaviour of the form, which is submitting.  Which is what he wants to stop...

Comment: Then why is he posting in there that it is still refreshing?

Comment: Because `.validate()` sometimes breaks if any syntax is improper.

Comment: [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5UqRm/)  Nothing is refreshing when `return false` is properly used within `submitHandler:`.  Something else is causing refresh.

Comment: @Sparky gotcha, that works well.  Think I might start using something like that instead of the event attachment.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: No problem... it seems to be the number one misconception about this plugin's usage, so glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works fine, with only one modification:

`data: $("#addstudent").serialize()`

It makes no difference whether you have the `return false` or not.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with having this in your submitHandler's ajax's success handler:

```
`$('#results').load('addresults.php', function(){});`
```

Why not echo back some output from add.php and use it by adding `.done(function(data){}` to your `$.ajax({})` ?

... your example does not include the `#results` element, so perhaps that is causing your refresh? e.g. if you have `<body id="results">` :-) !!

Comment: I do have a div below the form that is #results for the results of addresults.php to be displayed in. I have the `$('#results').load('addresults.php', function(){});` part in there to load the results, because I don't know how to use the .done(function(data){} that you mentioned.